# Can a pickled object be reliably encoded as Postgres string (to be sent with NOTIFY)?

Tags: python, postgresql, pickle, psycopg2

[Postgres NOTIFY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-notify.html) supports only string literals (no binary data). I've managed to use it with a pickled object in a following way:

```
message = cPickle.dumps(objectFoo)
cursor = connection.cursor() # this is psycopg2 connection
cursor.execute("NOTIFY channelFoo, %s", [message])
```

However, if I some tricky bytes are put in the encoded object (for example '\x80' string). An error is returned from `execute()`:

> psycopg2.DataError: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x80

Is there a way around this? One that would allow to reliably serialize pickled object to Postgres string no matter what data the object holds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python pickles are binary sequences of bytes.  If you need to put a pickle in a string, then encode it.  Typical techniques include using base64 or uuencode.  Then decode it on the receiving side.

Comment: Yep, hex encode it or base64 it. The size will be increased, but it'll be easily and reliably decoded at the other end. The first time you add a non-Python client you're going to regret this design, though; personally if I could I'd send JSON or other structured somewhat portable data.

Comment: One significant problem of course is that NOTIFY and LISTEN have very little security.  This would allow anyone to send pickled objects to the app, and anyone to pull pickled objects from the stream.  I think it's really preferable to have them somewhere that you can control permission on the listeners (like a table).

Comment: Thanks, base64 encoding is a good solution. I was mislead by the pickle documentation that says that 'the pickle data format uses a printable ASCII representation' and though it should somehow work without additional encoding.

Comment: @ChrisTravers Aren't correct database credentials needed to connect and send notifications? This should prevent notifications from untrusted sources.

Comment: @JanWrobel, yes, but that means every database client attached can send (and eavesdrop on!) the notifications.  I see this as insufficient security just as granting all rights on all tables would be insufficient security.

Comment: @JanWrobel I was also mislead by the pickle documentation trying to do something similar. The issue has been discussed as [Python issue 2980](http://bugs.python.org/issue2980).